# How can tornado catch interrupt of client

Tags: http, tornado

I want to handler tornado( ver = 4.0 ) when user break off his request to my tornado HTTP server, but I don't know when this event happens.For example, I start the server ,and run a curl command to request it,then I interrupt the curl while it is requesting.  Help please, thank you!

Here is my operation
[image: tornado.gif]

I read the doc and found `on_finish` method, but the method will be called when a request finish.

```py
# coding=u8
import time
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print('Start %s.'%time.strftime('%F %H:%M:%S'))
        time.sleep(5)
        self.write('ok.')
        print('Finish %s.'%time.strftime('%F %H:%M:%S'))

    def on_finish(self):
        """Called after the end of a request.
        Override this method to perform cleanup, logging, etc.
        This method is a counterpart to `prepare`.  ``on_finish`` may
        not produce any output, as it is called after the response
        has been sent to the client.
        """
        print('Cancelled %s.'%time.strftime('%F %H:%M:%S'))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

How can I know when client cancel it's request during the request is handlering?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`on_connection_close()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch4.5/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_connection_close) method to detect when client closes the connection.
2. DON'T use `time.sleep` because it's a blocking function. Some of Tornado's async features won't work when you use a blocking function. Instead, use a non-blocking alternative like `gen.sleep`.

Example:

```
from tornado import gen

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield gen.sleep(5) # asynchronous sleep
        # ... do something else

    def on_connection_close(self):
        print('Cancelled %s.'%time.strftime('%F %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My real code is synchronous, and I want to catch cancelled request and then save resources. Maybe  I was wrong.